# HTTP Links Not Opening in Android WebView in Android Studio Java?

Tags: android

When I open a URL that Starts with "https://" in android WebView it works properly and Play a Video in video player from same type of URL ("https://") video also plays well.
But whenever I tries to open non secure ("http://") URL WebView and Video Player both don't work. If you have any solution of this question then please answer ?

Comment: Does the same link work on a browser? May be the resource can only be reached through a secure connection?

Comment: Clear text traffic enabled in manifest?

Comment: Yes Same Link Working on Browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

You need to set Manifest and `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` properly. Below example is for http://test.com:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

res/xml/network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">test.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thanks It Worked ! How can I use it on Video Player because 'http' link still not playing video on video player.

Comment: @Ajay If your "video player" is about `VideoView`, there should be no difference from `WebView`. Because it's not a problem of `WebView` or `VideoView` but is a problem of your app's `Manifest`.